# Does Gradle have functionality like "npm link"?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm looking at options to separate our "mono-repo" so that each deployable service will have its own repo. One disadvantage of this is making changes to any common modules/libraries becomes tedious as it would require publishing the library first and then updating the version in gradle to use the changes.

npm appears to get around this through [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) which would allow you to modify the library and test it in your application before pushing your changes. I was wondering if gradle or any other build tool provides something similar for java applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) are what you want. The feature allows you to replace a project dependency with another build.

For example, imagine you have an application project called "Acme", which has a dependency on library "MyLib". Acme normally downloads MyLib from Maven Central or your company's artifact repository. But you want to make some changes to MyLib and test them with Acme, so you grab the source for MyLib, make the changes and then use the composite builds feature to run *Acme*'s build with your modified MyLib.

Note that you don't have to manually build MyLib or install the generated artifact anywhere. Gradle will automatically execute MyLib's build and include its artifact in Acme's build.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Though it does seem to be in the incubation phase.

Comment: But then this will be used primarily for local development so I don't think it'll matter too much